# Export raster to SQliteDB format in QGIS

Tags: qgis, sqlite

Does anyone know how I can export a raster to .SQliteDB format in QGIS?

I created georeferences of satellite images with the GIS program Global Mapper for Locus Map, but now I want to understand how this can be done in QGIS.

Comment: I believe that QGIS can only import vectorlayers into spatialLite.

Comment: What do you want to do with your exported data ?

Comment: @Kasper i want export it to .SQlitedb format for Locus Map and then ude it as a satellite layer in navigation programm

Comment: I have never used Locus Maps, but if what you want to do is add a Raster map you have created in QGIS as a Locus Map layer, I understand you should export your raster as Mbtiles  format, as it is 
 explained [here](https://help.locusgis.com/support/solutions/articles/47001094929-how-to-import-geotiff-or-geopdf)